# Не получается достать ссылку на товар на html странице

Tags: html

Есть сайт - https://maxi-retail.ru/yaroslavl/catalog/23. При клике на товары на этой странице открывается рамка с его характеристиками и описанием. Проблема состоит в том, что в html  коде сайта нет самой ссылки на товар в теге a, где может находиться ссылка и как мне ее достать?

Comment: нажать ф12, на вкладке Network включить фильтр hxr/ajax запросов и смотреть, что там происходит при клике

Comment: Спасибо, а как я могу достать все ссылки на товары на этой странице? (Пишу свой первый парсер и пока многих моментов не знаю)

Comment: Есть ajax запрос по типу `https://maxi.today/api/v4/delivery-web/product/get?key=11709&city_code=yaroslavl` обращайтесь меняя ключ, нужно вытянуть все ключи и по запросу получить ответ

Comment: просмотрите код страницы, там в ссылке/кнопке на которую кликаете, либо где то рядом будут указаны эти изменяющиеся id. короче из исходной страницы надо извлечь перечень айдишников, потом выполнить нужные запросы для получения данных.

Comment: А айдишники товаров можите найти в html коде `<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">....json с товарами и id`

Comment: В том скрипте я пока нашел только категории товаров и их айдишники

Comment: Да, нашел в том скрипте, большое спасибо